# JavaScript regular expression validation for domain name?

Tags: javascript

How to check a `valid domain name` and `username` with **regular expression** in JavaScript?

```
function validate()
{
    var patt1=new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\\[a-zA-Z0-9.-]$/);

    var text= document.getElementById('text1').value;

    alert(patt1.test(text));
}
```

But it does not work for me.

Comment: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know/

Comment: What does not work? In which format do you want to accept them, why only alphanumerical characters?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
function CheckIsValidDomain(domain) { 
    var re = new RegExp(/^((?:(?:(?:\w[\.\-\+]?)*)\w)+)((?:(?:(?:\w[\.\-\+]?){0,62})\w)+)\.(\w{2,6})$/); 
    return domain.match(re);
}
```

try this its work for me.

Comment: This may work but it's confusing to pass a regexp literal to a RegExp constructor as @Bergi pointed out in their answer.

Comment: Not an answer. Test with "www.google.com", "google.com", "google.co.uk", and "www.google.co.uk". Validation also implies returning a boolean and this does not do that.

Answer (score 5):

Don't mix up the [`RegExp` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) with [regex literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Creating_a_Regular_Expression). Use either

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\\[a-zA-Z0-9.-]$/
```

or

```
new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\\\\[a-zA-Z0-9.-]$");
```

Not sure what the backslash does in there, btw. Did you want to match a dot? In literal, use `\.`, in string use `\\.`.

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
<script>
    function frmValidate() {
        var val = document.frmDomin.name.value;
        if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9](?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})+$/.test(val)) {
            alert("Valid Domain Name");
            return true;
        } else {
            alert("Enter Valid Domain Name");
            val.name.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: how about the 2 letter domains?

Comment: @Touchpad Try this: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9](?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})+$/`

Comment: @ZefirZdravkov this domain does not work: www.2test.com

Comment: @Touchpad `^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9](?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,})+$`

Comment: that neither accounts for slash nor dash

Answer (score 1):

check this: http://shauninman.com/archive/2006/05/08/validating_domain_names

```
/^([a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+((a[cdefgilmnoqrstuwxz]|aero|arpa)|(b[abdefghijmnorstvwyz]|biz)|(c[acdfghiklmnorsuvxyz]|cat|com|coop)|d[ejkmoz]|(e[ceghrstu]|edu)|f[ijkmor]|(g[abdefghilmnpqrstuwy]|gov)|h[kmnrtu]|(i[delmnoqrst]|info|int)|(j[emop]|jobs)|k[eghimnprwyz]|l[abcikrstuvy]|(m[acdghklmnopqrstuvwxyz]|mil|mobi|museum)|(n[acefgilopruz]|name|net)|(om|org)|(p[aefghklmnrstwy]|pro)|qa|r[eouw]|s[abcdeghijklmnortvyz]|(t[cdfghjklmnoprtvwz]|travel)|u[agkmsyz]|v[aceginu]|w[fs]|y[etu]|z[amw])$/i
```

Comment: 2 letter domains?

Answer (score -1):

This code support sub-domains too:

```
^(([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$
```

Comment: late to the party but how about google.co.uk or hm.com ?