# Regex for domain verification with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I want to create a regular expression to verify domain names.

I've searched a lot on StackOverflow and I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27776532/1014588), which ignores the http and folders and checks only for domain.

### QUOTE

```
var pattern = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9](?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})+$', 'i');
```

But since I'm not a wizard and I've long ago given up on trying to understand Regex, [I placed it on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lB9rA1/1) which shows me that '**localhost**' is not a match. The problem is when I execute the following code ([jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/o6yL2w1f/)):

```
var origin = 'localhost';
var pattern = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9](?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})+$', 'i');
console.log(origin, pattern.test(origin));
```

It returns true (localhost should not be matched). Why?

---

Edit: For some reason, people thought I WANTED **localhost** to be recognized as a domain. **BUT IT'S THE OPPOSITE!** If you read the question, you'll see that it's returning true although it should return false.

Comment: For a start, if you're using a *string* to define the regex, you need to escape that backslash.

Comment: Try: `pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9](?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})+$/;`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I thought that the backslash was escaping the dot...

Comment: More importantly: This regex completely fails to handle anything other than the letters A-Z in the English alphabet. We have more expressive TLDs now. I don't think I'd try to validate anything other than that I had at least one character, a dot, and at least one character. And that will, of course, fail for `localhost` as well, because `localhost` isn't a domain name.

Comment: @minseong: It would do in an regex literal. In a **string** literal, `\.` is `.` (because the backslash is an escape in the string literal that escapes the dot, which doesn't need escaping, and ends up doing thing; the regex engine never sees that backslash).

Comment: `localhost` isn't a domain name. It's a hostname.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh yes, of course :P

Comment: And why did I get a -1? Isn't it a legit question?

Comment: @Marco - this is just a wild guess, but I would expect the `-1` is because there are already seventeen thousand questions on SO about how to match a domain with a regex (but largely in the form of trying to match an _email_ address with a regex). n.b. I didn't vote either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Regex101, you are entering a literal regex, not a string. As your regex is correct (it is) localhost doesn't match. However, in your code, you are creating your regex using strings (bad idea), which means you have to escape each backslash.

You can prevent the issue using Regexp literals.

Just use your original regex with forward-slashes, i.e.

```js
var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9](?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})+$/i;
```

Or just escape backslashes:

```js
var pattern = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9](?:\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})+$', 'i');
```

Comment: I don't want to, I want it to fail. This answer helps me.

Comment: antitest 1.c.test.com

Comment: `(/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9](?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})+$/i).test('1.c.test.com')`
false

while it is valid domain name

Comment: or more real one: www.w3.org

Comment: @eicto I didn't make the regex. I just had to show OP why his code didn't work as they'd expected.

Comment: I upvoted you :) don't worry, I just show what is bad with this regex idea