# Domain Name Validation using Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate domain name (only), which is going to be entered into textbox.

**Acceptance Criteria:**

```
abc.com
abc.in
abc.pqr.com
abc.com/xyz
abc.com/xyz/pqr
no.matter.how-many.domain-name.com/anything
```

**Reject:**

```
http://example.com
(anything preceding with http:// or https:// or ftp://)
abc.com////
abc.com///xyz
.....likewise
```

**I have/had tried this:**

```
^[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.?)^[a-z0-9]?$/i
```

But it doesn't take: abc.com/xyz or abc.com/  *(that is in my acceptance criteria)*

**(After that)Also tried this:**

`/([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+[.com|.in|.org]+(\[\?%&=]*)?/`

This overcome above problem,**But** it also take like: `http://example.com` *(that is in my reject criteria)*

I am not more good at Regular expressions, so, **what will be the regular expression for above scenario.**
*(Any modifications do i need in existing code?)*

Comment: Have you do any search? Eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027854/javascript-regular-expression-validation-for-domain-name

Comment: Visited/Searched, It does not allow me to enter like this: `abc.com/`

Comment: It works same like: `^[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.?)^[a-z0-9]?$/i`

Comment: I would strongly discourage the use of regex for domain validation. You're more likely to miss a lot of valid domains and possibly allow invalids. Domain names are a bit more complex than most people think.

Comment: But, its requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves my problem:

```
^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})(\/(?:[\/\w \.-]*)*\/?)?([\/?#].*)?
```

[This Article](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know--net-6149) helps.

**Edit:** Not Working. Also accepting `..com` and `example.com/////abc`

Comment: What about `..com` ? ;).

Comment: Ufff.....!!! I am stuck here.....!!! Not going to work this...!!!! Anyone here to suggest correct one ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/^[\w\-]+\.\w[\w\-\.]*((\/\w+)*|\/)$/igm
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lN7wC5/2)

Comment: Wrong. Gives error when : `abc.com`

Answer (score -1):

This was the best I could come up with. Didn't really check it too much

`^((?:[^:\/\.\s]+\.)+[^:\/\.\s]+(?:(?:\/[^:\/\.\s]+)*))$`

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vI7cW8/1)